# Access Creation date for Dynamo DB table using golang SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

I need to access the creation date field for the dynamo db table as part of the golang SDK. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the Table creation date using DescribeTable API.  [Please refer AWS Doc for more information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB.DescribeTable).

Go SDK has API to [DescribeTable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB.DescribeTable).

Use the  "CreationDateTime" property in the output.